# DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement. When perform save operation for @OneToOne JPA mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am getting "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement" exception while saving the object into the repository.

Requirement: Plan will have only one Cpricing Object so I have added @OneToOne mapping. Below is the expected table structure.

```
Plan table
-------------
id | planname

Cpricing table
----------
id | cdata | plan_id(fk)
```

I have below code changes in Entity classes:

```
Plan {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pl")//created one to one mapping between the cPricing
    private CPricing priceInfo;
}
    
CPricing {       
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //created one to one mapping between the plan
    @JoinColumn(name = "plan_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Plan pl;
}
```

An Exception is thrown when trying to save Plan object containing CPricing object.

Is the mapping correct ?

Comment: Could you please share the entire stack trace, it seems one of the fields in your entity class is null whch is causing the issues while persisting.

Answer (score 1):

Here you put `@JoinColumn` on `CPricing` side, so `CPricing` is the owner of relation you should also set plan for `CPricing`  when you save object in db.
You should do something like `Cpricing.setPl(plan)` before save.